# Achieving Pagespeed Insight's Image Compression result

Tags: pagespeed, image-compression

I am getting a low Pagespeed Insight score because of an image that PageSpeed tells me should be optimized (37% compression)

- Image is:  https://d3m9459r9kwism.cloudfront.net/img/hands3.jpg
- PageSpeed report here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https://d3m9459r9kwism.cloudfront.net/img/hands3.jpg

But when I run jpegoptim, the image already seems to be optimized!

```
MacBook:img me$ jpegoptim --strip-all -p hands3.jpg
hands3.jpg 2000x1200 24bit N JFIF  [OK] 237631 --> 237631 bytes (0.00%), skipped.
```

I don't see how I can achieve this 37% compression. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagespeed Insights has changed and will now output recommendations that includes lossy compression of JPG images.
PageSpeed currently tries to change your JPG images quality to 85. Reducing the quality to 85 removed the warning.